union of n number of tables that starts with same prefix on a particular database and schema in DBT
I am trying to make macro in dbt that reads files from a specific database,schema and unions them.
So as first step I am storing all the table names from information schema in snowflake which has all tables that starts with GENERAL%.After this reading this in for loop and using source function to create relation which can be fed to dbt_utils.union_relations. Looks like this-
{% macro union_files_starting_with_gen() %}
{% set database_name = ‘X_DEV' %}
{% set schema_name = ‘X__AUDIT' %}
{% set prefix = 'GEN%' %}

  {% set file_names_query = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM " ~ database_name ~   ".INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '" ~ schema_name ~ "' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '" ~  prefix ~ "'" %}
{% set file_names = run_query(file_names_query) %}
{% do dbt_utils.log_info("Contents of file_names: " ~ file_names) %}

{% set sources = [] %}

{% for file_name_row in file_names %}
    {%- set table_name = file_name_row.TABLE_NAME %}
    {%- set full_table_name = schema_name ~ '.' ~ table_name %}
    {%- do dbt_utils.log_info("Processing table: " ~ full_table_name) %}
    {%- set source_obj = source(schema_name, table_name) %}
      {%- do dbt_utils.log_info("source: " ~ source_obj) %}
    {%- do sources.append(source_obj) %}
    {%- do dbt_utils.log_info("Source object: " ~ source_obj) %}
{% endfor %}

with unioned as (
    {{ dbt_utils.union_relations(relations=sources) }}
)

select * from unioned;

{% endmacro %}

Here till {%- do dbt_utils.log_info("Processing table: " ~ full_table_name) %} ,I see values on terminal, however  {%- set source_obj = source(schema_name, table_name) %}  is not working. What I am looking for is to make relation to pass on to union_relations.
Would appreciate any help!! Thanks
have tried to dry run the macro


As per dbt docs try to avoid constructing references/sources on your own. You can use api.Relation.create method or adapter.get_relation method instead.


Relation object should always be used instead of interpolating values with {{ schema }}.{{ table }} directly.
2. For the X_DEV.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES it's better to use sources.yml file and reference the table from it (again, try to avoid hardcoding table references)
3. As your macro does not have any arguments, you might want to consider switching it to a model (but it depends on the use case, I guess)
4. Consider moving schema_name = 'X__AUDIT' to dbt_profile.sql as a variable
5. Leverage dbt_utils.get_column_values macro

A possible solution
sources.yml:
version: 2

sources:
  - name: metadata
    database: X_DEV
    schema: information_schema
    tables:
      - name: tables

files_starting_with_gen.sql:
{% set schema_name = 'X__AUDIT' %}
{% set table_names = dbt_utils.get_column_values(
        table=source('metadata', 'tables'),
        where="table_schema = '" ~ schema_name ~ "' AND table_name like 'GEN%'",
        column='table_name',
) %}
{% set sources = [] %}

{% for table_name in table_names %}
    {%- do sources.append(
        adapter.get_relation(
            database=source('metadata', 'tables').database,
            schema=schema_name,
            identifier=table_name
            )
        ) %}
{% endfor %}

with unioned as (
    {{ dbt_utils.union_relations(relations=sources) }}
)

select * from unioned

